# Is my explanation of a USB battery pack correct?

Tags: batteries, usb, capacity

Being the most technically proficient person in my office I was asked to answer this, but not being sure of myself, I wanted to make sure I explained this well.
A customer asked of the device "how many watts is it". The only technical data I had onit was it's mAH (2200). Our guess is that they might not really be asking the right question, so we wanted to give them an answer that was better than their question. I told my boss this:

> The USB chargers should provide power like this:
>  
>   500 mA  
>   5 V 
>   2.5 W
>
> Since it is 2200mAH and it outputs 500mA, it would be expected to last
>   up to 4.4 hours, depending on the device it is charging.

Is my explanation (mostly) correct?

Comment: "Our guess is that they might not really be asking the right question" +1

Comment: "How many watts?" is a valid question, maybe better expressed as "What is the average/peak power output?". So why did you guess that the customer was in fact asking for something else?

Comment: It's a valid question, but the answer is usually the same for all USB devices, so it's not very useful to know that.

Comment: @realtime, I figured that if the person was savvy enough to ask that question intentionally, they's be savvy enough to look it up (Since it is a USB device and USB is a standard.)

Comment: Will the 5V stay at 5V for the full 4.4 hours at 500mA (across your specified temperature range)

Comment: @Andyaka that's why I put "(mostly)" in my last line. I don't know what all might influence actual performance. I don't know if all USB devices draw the maximum current etc.

Comment: @TecBrat USB chargers often only partially implement the specification (e.g. only the nominal 5V and the connectors) and/or implement optional specifications related to charging. In fact, many USB chargers deliver much more than 500mA.

Comment: It seems to me the customer wanted to know either "How long will this battery last when used in my application?" or possibly "How much energy is in it?"

Comment: @realtime I have no problem with the question "how many watts".  The question was "how many watts [are in this battery]?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, almost all those USB battery packs are based on a single lithium-polymer/ion/something cell. Marketing being what it is, most of the time the capacity advertised on the box is actually the cell capacity. Since those battery cells have a ~3.7V output, the battery pack have to convert the 3.7V into 5V with a boost. In your case, assuming the boost is a good one with 90% efficiency, the number you're looking for is, at best:  **2200 x 3.7 x 0.9 = 7.3Wh**

Answer (score 1):

The question "how many watts is it" cannot be answered. At best one can try to answer the question "How many Wh (watt-hours) is it?" That would *approximately* be $$2200\text{mAh} × 5\text{V} \approx 10\text{Wh}$$

This means the battery can supply a 10W load for the duration of 1 hour. Or 5W for 2hrs, ... Theoretically that is. In practice you don't want to discharge your battery all the way. Also the efficiency of a battery is not 100% and to complicate things even further, efficiency (charge you get out of the battery vs charge you put in it) varies with load. As Andy notes in one of the comments, the outpu voltage of the device probably varies over time, the above formula does not account for that either.

Answer (score 0):

Your assuming that the devices use 2.5W/500mA. Some Samsung Devices use 700mA, iphones 5W/1A and iPads 10.5W/2.1A. Some newer tablets even more than that. Some devices use less than 500mA.

Not considering efficiency or actual output vs marketed output, and going just on the stated numbers, your response should be "5v, up to x mA, so **up to** (5 * x) Watts." And if you want to go further "It has a capacity of Y mAh, so (5v * Y mAH) Watt Hours, which means **up to** N Hours at Z Watts".